# WebAPI - How can I remove case sensivity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm doing a search function in WebAPI but it only returns the item if it's correct accordingly to the XML data. For example, it will only return the item if I write "Milk" or "Apple". How can I make it return these items if I write "milk", "apple" or maybe "aPpLe"?

**Controller:**

```
   public IHttpActionResult GetItems(string name)
    {

        List<Item> allItems = GetAllItems();

        return Ok(allItems.Where(i => i.Name.Contains(name)));
    }
```

Comment: `allItems.Where(i => i.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can convert the strings to lower case.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetItems(string name)
{
    List<Item> allItems = GetAllItems();

    return Ok(allItems.Where(i => i.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())));
}
```

I did not test it but it should work.

Comment: *I did not test it but it should work.* [no, it won't](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html)

Answer (score -1):

### CODE

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetItems(string name)
 {
     List<Item> allItems = GetAllItems();

     //We are ignoring the Case Sensitivity and comparing the items with name
     return Ok(allItems.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(name,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: Equals not equals Contains

Comment: @Selvin We are comparing the individual item from allItems list using Equals(name,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) which will internally ignore the case of my name.

Comment: If i have an element which i am iterating in my list and comparing with name (input parameter) i can use equals as compare to contains as it will give me a reliable result.                                                                                                                               For Ex:- If i have a word Mapple and i use contains for apple keyword in my resulting output i will get a failure as i am looking for apple keyword not Mapple.

Comment: Milk shake, apple pie... For search we rather use contains... Also OP used Contains in his code...